My nestjs interface cannot be accessed on the mobile phone
I have a website that has been deployed on a server. I can successfully access the interface to obtain data on my computer, but not on my phone. When I open the browser console on my phone, two errors are displayed:
An error occurred {"headers": {"normalizedNames": {}, "lazyUpdate": null, "headers": {}}, "status": 0, "statusText": "Unknown Error", "url": "https://www.flowersink.cn/blog", "ok": false, "name": "HttpErrorResponse", "message": "Http failure response for https://www.flowersink.cn/blog: 0 Unknown Error", "error": {"isTrusted": true}}

ERROR Http failure response for https://www.flowersink.cn/blog: 0 Unknown Error

When I use my computer to access https://www.flowersink.cn/blog, the data is obtained normally.
When I use my phone to access https://www.flowersink.cn/blog, if it is an Apple phone, it will display An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.
If it is an Android phone, it will show a DNS resolution error.
I can ensure that there is no problem with my SSL certificate. How should I solve this problem?
The solutions I have tried so far:
In the IGNIX configuration:
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3, delete TLSv1.1.

Modify the encryption configuration to:
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305';

Add to the nestjs project:
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

